# React native navigation between Tab and Stack navigator || React navigation 5.o

Tags: react-native

I am working on a Project which includes Material Bottom tab navigation and Drawer navigation. Below is my screen structure.

Tab1 - Home, Contact

Tab2 - More

Here, I want to navigate from Home screen to More screen without clicking the bottom tab button.

I am getting the below error If I try to navigating from Home to More.

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"more"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

What is the method to navigate between these screens using navigate('more').

Comment: Do you have access to the "navigation" variable?
If so, use: navigation.navigate('More');

Comment: Just now I checked the answer. I should have used navigation.jumpTo('more) instead of navigation.navigate('more'). Thank you!